# ListView showing only first element in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-nestedscrollview

I need to make a list in my NestedScrollView but showing only first element. I tried with `android:fillViewport="true"` but hothing happened. I know that ListView has scrollable incorporated in itself.

my xml :

```
<layout >
<data>
    <variable
        name="home"
        type="com.nswd.successplan.ui.fragments.homeFragment.HomeViewModel" />
</data>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f4f7"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.homeFragment.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#f0f4f7">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_TV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Dashboard"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/first_row_LL"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_row_LL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date_time_LL"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dashboard_TV">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/my_plan_LV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0f5acf"
                android:onClick="@{home::updateMyPlanOnClick}"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_assignment" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/home_fragment_update_my_plan_TV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Update My Plan"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/update_my_budget_LV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#4d88ff"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:onClick="@{home::updateMyBudgetOnCLick}"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Update My Budget"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contact_advisor_LV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0e4087"
                android:onClick="@{home::contactAdvisorOnCLick}"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_support" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Contact advisor"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_time_LL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#884dff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/second_row_LL"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_row_LL">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/date_image_IMG"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_date_range_24" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:text="29.09.2020"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_row_LL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pie_chart_expenditures_TV"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_time_LL">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/plan_last_update_LV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Plan Last Updated"
                    android:textColor="@color/hints_black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="21"
                    android:textColor="#3297e9"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Aug 2017"
                    android:textColor="#a0b4bf"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/until_retirement_LV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Until Retirement"
                    android:textColor="@color/hints_black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="33"
                    android:textColor="#3297e9"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Years"
                    android:textColor="#a0b4bf"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/out_of_debt_LV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Out of Debt Date"
                    android:textColor="@color/hints_black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="20"
                    android:textColor="#3297e9"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Aug 2017"
                    android:textColor="#a0b4bf"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pie_chart_expenditures_TV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Monthly Expenditures"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pie_chart_expenditures_LL"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/second_row_LL" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pie_chart_expenditures_LL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list_view_pie_chart_legend"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pie_chart_expenditures_TV">

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                android:id="@+id/pie_chart_reports_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_pie_chart_legend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pie_chart_expenditures_LL"
            tools:listitem="@layout/pie_chart_list_item" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

my item view:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="legend"
            type="com.nswd.successplan.model.PieChartLegendModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/legend_color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dot_list_item_pie_chart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expenditure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Debt Payments"
            android:textColor="#197ad8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/costs_expenditure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="7,555" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: are you using pie_chart_list_item layout for the listView items ? if yes post that xml file code too

Comment: add `nestedscrollingenabled="false"` in your listview. t may help

Comment: @AgentP i posted it

Comment: Try changing the `costs_expenditure` and `expenditure` id's textViews height to wrap_content  instead  match parent

Comment: @AgentP nope,still the same